# Validating a multipart file on upload in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app that allows me to upload a file as follows:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveEmployee( @RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    employeeS3Service.save(multipartFile);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

What i want to do is before I save to s3, I want to validate its contens. Is there an easy way of doing this? so i read each line and check contents?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can validate the contents of the file using the `InputStream` provided by `MultipartFile` to read the content and then perform your validation logic:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Validator {
    public void validateFileContents(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Perform your validation logic for each line
                if (!isValid(line)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid content in the file");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isValid(String line) {
        // Your validation logic here
        // For example, check if the line meets certain criteria
        // Return true if valid, false otherwise
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1555190, if my answer was helpful and acceptable for you, click accept it as answer

Comment: @user1555190, was this answer useful for you? It's always good to leave at least some feedback, as this will show that you respect the community members who are helping YOU resolve YOUR issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a validtor class like that:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class FileValidator {

    public static boolean validateFile(MultipartFile file) {
        // Perform your validation checks here
        try {
            // Read the file contents
            byte[] fileBytes = file.getBytes();
            String fileContent = new String(fileBytes);

            // Example validation
            if (fileContent.contains("invalidKeyword")) {
                // File content is not valid
                return false;
            }

            // Add more validation checks as needed

        } catch (Exception e) {
           // handel error
           return false;
        }

        // File content is valid
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use the FileValidator:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveEmployee( @RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile multipartFile) {


      if (!FileValidator.validateFile(file)) {
           return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .body("Invalid file content");
        }

     // Proceed with saving the file to S3 or perform other actions
     employeeS3Service.save(multipartFile);
      
     return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully");
}
```